# How can a custom UIPrintPageRenderer subclass respond to changes in the UIPrintInteractionController user interface?

Tags: printing, uikit

I have created a custom `UIPrintPageRenderer` subclass that is assigned to a `UIPrintInteractionController`.

The user might change some values in the `UIPrintInteractionController` such as whether to print in color or grayscale, or maybe change from orientation from portrait to landscape, etcetera.

I want my custom `UIPrintPageRenderer` to respond to such changes in the `UIPrintInteractionController` user interface, however I have not been able to find a solution.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?